# How to remove a column of a list on SharePoint

Tags: list, 2007, column, publishing-site

I am using SharePoint 2007 + Windows Server 2008 with SharePoint 2007's publishing portal template. I have created a list with datasheet view on a page (I add the list by adding a Web Part -> then select the list control to add it as a web part to the page.) When create the list, I have added 5 columns, and inserted some rows.

My question is, how to remove one column of the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that you totally want to Remove the Column from the List in that case

Go to List -> Select Settings - > List Settings -> You will see all the Columns listed ->Select the column you want to delete and in the Change Column Page - > Delete Button.

In case if you want the column to be removed from the View, you need to edit the view and uncheck the column you dont want.

Comment: Cool, question answered!